# Extruding Three.js Geometry

Tags: javascript, svg, three.js

I'm trying to render a complex 2D path in `Three.js` and then extrude it. [This](http://pastebin.com/7prb3HT5) is the path I'm trying to render, here is a preview where the red color is my filled path:

[image]

I'm using [svg-mesh-3d](https://github.com/mattdesl/svg-mesh-3d) to transform the SVG path to a `simplicial complex`, this works great, after that I use [three-simplicial-complex](https://github.com/Jam3/three-simplicial-complex) to convert the `simplicial complex` to a `Three.js` Geometry, great until here, the problem is now, that this Three.js geometry is flat, it's a 2D object and I can't extrude it with `ExtrudeGeometry` because it's not a `Shape`.

Is there any way or alternative to extrude this object? I tried other libraries like `d3-threeD.js` to convert from SVG to a Three.js shape but none of them works well with complex SVG paths like this.

Comment: [this](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_extrude_shapes2) example is about how to extrude svg paths. And with your svg path it's working fine [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/fewwnd1r)